# Show and hide buttons for debug/inspector/navigator disappeared or relocated in Xcode toolbar

Tags: swift, xcode, button

The buttons for showing or hiding the debug area/navigator/inspector have all been switched up (the debug disappeared altogether). Can't figure out how to make them all appear on the top right corner of Xcode again. I've tried showing and hiding the toolbar, restarting, etc. Any help is appreciated. [Missing buttons screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roP4z.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code within the post, not as image.

Comment: It's not a code issue, I think it's the new update that removed the view buttons for the debug/inspector/navigator panes.